# URL link for custom module in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am currently developing a custom module.
What I want is to have a nice URL, because right now it looks like this:

```
domain.com/flower-deliveries?city=Hamburg&id_country=1&country=Germany
```

I already added a new page to link to the custom module, the page name is flower-deliveries, but still I have the parameters that I have to "hide".

Instead, of that link above I would like a URL like this:

```
domain.com/flower-deliveries-1-Hamburg-Germany.html
```

I tried 2 methods, but none of them worked..

The first one, was to add a hookModuleRoutes in my controller, just like below:

```
public function hookModuleRoutes($params)
{
    return array(
        'module-vpages-dpage' => array(
            'controller' => 'dpage',
            'rule' => 'flower-deliveries{-:id_country}{-:country}{-:city}.html',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id_country' => array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'id_country'),
                'city' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'city'),
                'country' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'country')
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'vpages',
                'controller' => 'dpage'
            )
        )
    );      
}
```

And then, in the controllers install:

```
$this->registerHook('moduleRoutes');
```

That didn't worked, so I tried to override the Dispatcher class, by adding a custom module route:

```
'module-vpages-dpage' => array(
    'controller' => 'dpage',
    'rule' => 'flower-deliveries{-:id_country}{-:country}{-:city}.html',
    'keywords' => array(
        'id_country' => array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_country'),
        'city' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'city'),
        'country' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'country'),
    ),
    'params' => array(
        'fc' => 'module',
        'module' => 'vpages',
        'controller' => 'dpage'
    )
),
```

When using that custom rule, the link `http://domain.com/flower-deliveries?city=Hamburg&id_country=1&country=Germany` was tranformed in `http://domain.com/flower-deliveries?module_action=list` and it didn't worked and was redirecting me to the first page.

Could some one tell me what am I doing wrong?
I've spent hours of reading how it should be done and it should be just like the ones above..

Thank you!

Comment: Your first method is ok, but it needs to be in your module class not in controller. And in your rule, you have defined `'rule' => 'flower-deliveries{-:id_country}{-:country}{-:city}.html'` however pretty url link you posted you use `-1-Hamburg-Germany`. You're using city before country but in rule its defined in different order.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I modified the module, to have the hook inside the module file but still nothing.. it doesn't show as supposed..

Comment: Define your rule like this `'rule' => 'flower-deliveries-{:id_country}-{:country}-{:city}.html'` and see if it works. I tested your first solution and PrestaShop throws out exception however this way worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revert all edits that you have done :).

Try this way:

For example, this is core module file `rootofps/modules/vpages/vpages.php`

```
class VPages extends Module {
   public function __construct(){
       $this->name = 'vpages';
       $this->author = 'you';
       $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
       $this->version = '1.0.0';
       $this->controllers = array('dpage');

       parent::__construct();
   }

   // This is the function in your core module file (not in controller)
   public function install(){
       return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('moduleRoutes')
   }

   public function hookModuleRoutes($params){
      $my_link = array(
          'vpages' => array(
              'controller' => 'dpage',
              'rule' => 'flower-deliveries{-:id_country}{-:country}{-:city}.html',
              'keywords' => array(
                  'id_country' => array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_country'),
                  'country' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'country'),
                  'city' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'city'),
               ),
               'params' => array(
                   'fc' => 'module',
                   'module' => 'vpages'
               )
           )
        );
        return $my_link;
    }
}
```

Now the controller `rootofps/modules/vpages/controllers/front/dpage.php`

```
class VpagesDpageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->setTemplate('dapage.tpl');
    }
}
```

And now the view `rootofps/modules/vpages/views/templates/front/dpage.tpl`

```
id_country = {$smarty.get.id_country}<br>
country = {$smarty.get.country}<br>
city={$smarty.get.city}<br>
```

This 'skeleton' works at 100% :), by the way, notice that if you give an url like this `mydomain.com/flower-deliveries?id_country=1&country=italy&city=rome` PrestaShop will not transform your url in a clearly url as you want.
But an url like this `mydomain.com/flower-deliveries-2-italy-rome.html` will be routes properly :)

Comment: Hi, I have tried it like in your answer, but it doesn't work at all.. I still have the ugly url link.. :(

Comment: Check if the database it's 'dirty' of your previous tests (ps_meta, ps_meta_lang), remove any override of dispatcher.

Comment: I don't have any override regarding this topic, so it should be clean right now.. but I don't get it why it's not working..

Comment: I've just made a test: http://ps1615.tanzows.it/en/flower-deliveries-2-salerno-italy.html

Comment: By the way, notice that the url like this `mydomain.com/flower-deliveries?id_country=1&country=france&city=paris` don't will be 'transformed' in a clearly url.

Comment: You were right, it works! I forgot to uninstall and then reinstall the module back again! But now, it troughs an error: "is not a valid module name" or if I disable the MODE DEV, it gives me a 404 error.. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Check if there are a syntax errors, like `vpage` instead of `vpages`, it's a common mistake :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121266/discussion-between-rosuandreimihai-and-sarcom).