# How create clean route url from smarty template prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to create custom from my module to controller new page but have some variable to send with. I not to want to show like this `http://website.com/en/modelurl?id=17`. i want to route like this `http://website.com/en/modelurl/17`. and i create like from my model class and past it to smarty template

`$this->smarty->assign(array(
                'getlink' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('tmmanufacturerblock','display'),
            ));`.

smarty template link: `<a href="{$getlink}?id={$variable}">`.

So how can i create clean url Like this:`http://website.com/en/modelurl/17`

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013727/url-link-for-custom-module-in-prestashop-1-6) question (and answer)

Comment: If you enable friendly url the Link class create a friendly url