# Dynamic URL on category filter - Prestashop

Tags: url, search, filter, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to build a custom 'category' page displaying the products (car parts) that are linked to a certain type of vehicle.

My current URL looks like this:

```
http://prestashop.dev/cars?manufacturer=BMW&model=3%20Series&year=2003&engine-type=Petrol&engine-size=1.8
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
http://prestashop.dev/cars/manufacturer-BMW/model-3-Series/year-2003/engine-type-Petrol/engine-size-1.8
```

How is this possible? I don't want to go and create a custom URL in the `SEO & URLs` section for every possible combination as the manufacturer BMW has multiple models each having multiple years, etc.

Also, it needs to be able to move around in the url. Ie: if they only provide a manufacturer and a year, the url must be:

```
http://prestashop.dev/cars/manufacturer-BMW/year-2003
```

Any idea on how to do this inside of the module in Prestashop 1.6?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013727/url-link-for-custom-module-in-prestashop-1-6/39017261

Answer (score 0):

As per our knowledge, it is not possible to achieve this in PrestaShop. We recommend you to use hash in the URL and to make URL SEO friendly don't forget to use ! after hash.

You can check the same by visiting the following URL:

https://www.1motoshop.com/parts#!2015--Harley-Davidson--FLTRXS-Road-Glide-Special